# Why does Git show me this local unpushed commits?

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit

I have a strange behaviour and I don't understand what can be the cause.

Basically:

1. I do the development locally in NetBeans
2. Then push to Bitbucket
3. Finally, pull from the production server

So, I never do commits from the production server, I only pull there.

So after I did my last pull:

```
-bash-4.2$ git pull origin master
```

Then I checked the status and gave me this:

```
-bash-4.2$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Then I went to see what commits were those:

```
-bash-4.2$ git cherry -v
+ 2456db712fafab4b845a128711820ca107475e1f Remove comment added by josepluis to yiic horde loader
+ 8b9edf42c0d5177cd77f061160e27580098b745c Fix small bug when ordering pictures that was executing the update on wrong table
```

And if I check on Bitbucket I see those are not local commits made from the production server but they are my commits that I did from my computer and pushed to Bitbucket.

[image: Bitbucket master branch]

So why is Git from the production server consider those commits, local unpushed commits?

Comment: A blind guess would be : someone made a `push -f` between your two pulls. Is this possible ?

Comment: You could look at the reflog for `origin/master` on your production server to see if this is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inspecting the reflog for `origin/master`, and check if there was a history rewrite between two of your pulls :

```
$ git reflog origin/master
ffac48d09 refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: fetch: fast-forward
d7dffce1c refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: fetch: fast-forward
e05806da9 refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: fetch: fast-forward
aeddbfdfa refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}: fetch: fast-forward
...

$ git log --oneline --graph ffac48d09 d7dffce1c e05806da9
# and check if the sequence of commits is linear, or if it "forked" at some point
```

---

Two ways to avoid being bitten by rewrites (and `git pull`'s automatic merge or rebase) :

1. stop using `git pull`, run `git fetch`, inspect how `origin/master` evolved, and depending on what you need :

   - `git merge origin/master` / `git rebase origin/master` : run the same action as `git pull`, but *after* being informed that the history changed
   - `git reset --hard origin/master` : do not try to *merge*, just use this specific commit
2. tell `git pull` to only move on fast forwards : `git pull --ff-only`